# Delay evaluation of Chop until its argument has no symbols? (== has this behavior, Chop does not)

Tags: function-construction, assignment

With Equal (==), if `a` and `b` are undefined symbols, `a==b` does not evaluate. This way we can say something like `a==b/.{a->1,b->1}` I want this behavior for `Chop`.

In other words, right now, `Chop[a]` gives `a`, but I want it to give `Chop[a]`.

Ultimately I want the following behavior:
`Chop[a]/.a->10^-17` to evaluate to 0 (right now it evaluates to `10^-17`).

Comment: ``Hold[Chop[a]] /. a -> 10.^-17 //ReleaseHold``. Note that the number should not be exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your own `chop` function that only operates on numeric quantities:

```
ClearAll[chop]
chop[a_?NumericQ] := Chop[a]

chop[b]
(* chop[b] *)

chop[b] /. b -> 1.*^-17
(* 0 *)
```

Note that, as mentioned by Domen in comments, an arbitrary-precision number like `10^-17` won't be chopped to zero: you need machine-precision input. You could add a call to `N` in the definition of `chop` (`Chop[N@a]`) if you really want that behavior.

Comment: is this how Equal is defined?